# Make field required with lightning:inputField and lightning:recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-inputfield

There is no setting for the lightning:inputField to make it required.

idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKNbQAM
docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/specification

My lightning component is dynamic with all of the fields being passed through. I cannot find a way to make required fields required.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="{! v.sObjectName }"
                          recordId="{! v.recordId }"
                          recordTypeId="{! v.recordTypeId }"
                          class="slds-card slds-p-around_medium"
                          onsuccess="{! c.onsuccess }"
                          onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
                          >
 <aura:iteration items="{! column.Fields }" var="field">
 <lightning:inputField  fieldName="{! field.APIName }"  class="{!'slds-p-top_small slds-m-top_medium '+field.Behaviour}" disabled="{! field.Behaviour=='Readonly'}" />
</aura:iteration>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Any ideas on how to make an onsubmit function that can loop through N number of input fields and make them required?

Comment: I think this will help you. visit this link and let me know whether you are able to fix . https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207336/setting-attribute-required-to-lightninginputfield

Comment: Must be client-side validation. Validation rules are not enough.

Comment: @DanielHowell you got any solution or may be workaround?

Comment: No. No suggestions from anyone at the moment

Comment: @DanielHowell why can't you check if this field exists on the form and if so, is it filled? In my opinion you can do it using JS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OOTB, lightning:inputfield handles field validations that are configured through your object's field settings, so that would be the first place you want to check in order to make your fields "required".

If for whatever reason, the above is not an option (eventhough it should be), then adding an `aura:id` that identifies all your `lighting:inputfield` fields will enable you to simply 'fetch' all of them with component.find('yourAuraId') which returns an array you can iterate over to perform your field validations.

You can then bind your validation method to the onsubmit event and do a simple check for blank fields:

```
isFormValid: function (cmp, evt, helper) {
    const requiredFields = cmp.find('yourAuraId') || [];
    var isValid = true;
    requiredFields.forEach(e => {
        if (e.get('v.value')=='' || e.get('v.value').trim().length==0 ) {
            isValid = false;
        }
    });

    return isValid;
},
```

based on the what is returned by the validation method, you can proceed with submitting the form or not with `event.preventDefault();`       // stop the form from submitting

Comment: There is no auraId on lightning:inputField https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/specification

Comment: `aura:id` can be used on almost every component if not every, and it is not in the component specifications -> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_find_by_id.htm

Comment: I see that now.

Comment: When I Iuse event.preventDefault();  it does it job. Then I submit the form a second time and it passes the validation. But the form doesn't submit. If I reclick the button then it submits. So after adding a value it stops working for one click.

Comment: you will have to open a new post with the specifics =) comments are not for extended discussions

Comment: You are correct  PS. I just submitted it with cmp.find("PageLayoutForm").submit(eventFields);   and it worked

Comment: good job =)    - feel free to open a new post if you have other questions

Comment: This `cmp.find('yourAuraId') || [];` will break when it starts executing `forEach` if `cmp.find('yourAuraId')` returns one element, which is not an array

Answer (score 8):

[Winter20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_aura_components.htm) , required attribute available for `lightning:inputField` from winter 20

Comment: That's a savior. :)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified version of @glls answer:

```
isFormValid: function (component) {
    return (component.find('requiredField') || [])
        .filter(function (i) {
            var value = i.get('v.value');
            return !value || value == '' || value.trim().length === 0;
        })
        .map(function (i) {
            return i.get('v.fieldName');
        });
}
```

Then use as:

```
    var invalidFields = helper.isFormValid(component);
    if(invalidFields && invalidFields.length > 0){
        helper.reportUserError(
            'Please complete all required fields',
            'Incomplete: '+ invalidFields.join(', ')
        );
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
```

Where reportUserError is just a wrapper for error toast (or whatever logic you wanna do).

Unfortunate thing is it returns list of field API names - not sure is possible to get label.

What you'll also find probably useful is how to add a typical "required" asterisk to you component - [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207336/setting-attribute-required-to-lightninginputfield).

In the end your markup will be like this:

```
<lightning:inputField
                                class="customRequired"
                                aura:id="requiredField"
                                fieldName="Foo__c"/>
```

Comment: Note: might need to tweak it if only one required field is on screen.

Comment: Do you really need that check for `value == ''`? `!value` should be enough to verify if the string is empty.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense