# How to make field is required by using force:recordForm or force:recordEditform?

Tags: lightning

I have one pagelayout on object account. I make some fields are required on pagelayout level.When I am trying to achive this pagelayout with the help of recordform the required fields are not at all required.
Can you any one help on this?

Thanks
Dhanamjaya

Comment: [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207336/setting-attribute-required-to-lightninginputfield) is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213804/how-can-one-validate-recordeditform-fields-before-submitting-them-to-the-platf/213905#213905) to validation for Force:RecordEditForm or Force:RecordForm